# CSS3 Linear gradient on IE10

Tags: internet-explorer, css, internet-explorer-10

We have decided to finally support Internet Explorer, however only currently from 10. I have been reading up on the CSS support IE has and I wasn't sure if it was possible to currently do this in IE?

```
background: linear-gradient(bottom right,circle,rgba(0, 0, 0, .04),transparent 80px,transparent 100%);
```

Is there anyway to do this or does it still require falling back to a png?

Comment: Did you try it? What do you want it to look like?

Comment: Nothing currently happens. Just blank.

Comment: Need it to look like a shadow is fading out on the left side. It's for a horizontal rule.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful. Go there --> http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/cssgradientbackgroundmaker/

Comment: Milche. I don't normally ask such blunt questions. I have put in research and it seems to point a lot towards adding -ms- to the beginning. I'm currently in a hurry and apologize that my question was "Unclear and not useful" However the help provided would be of use to me!. I have visited that link previously but it lacks the ability to use opacity.

Comment: "Noting happens" because of the code. It's a mixture between a linear (ahem, the `linear-gradient` part) and a radial gradient (the `circle` part) and therefore cannot work (plus, `top right` is the older syntax, current one uses `to` for linear gradients and `at` for radial gradients). IE10 does support gradients and it's actually great with them (renders radial gradients better than Chrome of FF and it's the only browser that currently animates gradient angles or colors). So... do you want a linear or a radial gradient?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your OP declaration will not work. No, falling back to an image is not necessary. Your declaration is just NOT valid. Explain what you want to do between a 'linear' or a 'circular' gradient .. or just go to http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ and rebuild your line.

You are looking for something like this (cross-browser backward compatible):

```
.shadow {

background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.03) 31%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 32%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.03) 31%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 32%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.03) 31%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 32%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.03) 31%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 32%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=1 );
}
```

[jsFiddle with yours and mine](http://jsfiddle.net/SRUGf/428/) where you can play

**[Post notes]**

About IE: the "filter" rule is for IE9-, preview releases of IE10 used a "-ms" prefixed syntax, and IE10 onwards use the standard syntax.

For detailed information, see the [linear-gradient page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient).

Comment: Thank you. Simply all i needed to know. So fall-back to an image is the only option on IE10?

Comment: NO, 'fall-back' is not the way. Like user @RowlandShaw asked : What do you want it to look like?

Comment: Before adding a lot of lines of code that may not be needed (as gradient generators do) http://lea.verou.me/2013/04/can-we-get-rid-of-gradient-prefixes/ ColorZilla is great for beginners, but sadly, it makes it look like no browser yet supports the standard syntax (you can see that if you also choose to generate the comments). Which is not true. Current versions of IE, FF, Opera and Chrome all support gradients unprefixed.

Comment: @Ana, thanks for the comment. 2 things came to my mind after reading you : ''the standard syntax'' and ''supported by current versions () unprefixed.'' Somehow, css-level-3 is not standardized yet, and 'current versions of broswer is not like i suggested to the OP with 'cross-browser backward compatible'. Quoted from lea.verou.me **My opinion

Don’t use -ms- prefixed gradients, there’s absolutely zero point in doing so. Include -moz- for the less subtle gradients. No significant need for -o- gradients. -webkit- is still needed and probably will be at least until the end of 2013.**

Comment: If anyone stumbles across this as i did, please note that IE10 -requires- the "-ms" prefixed linear gradient. IE9 could do without, but IE10 necessitates another line in your style. It will ignore your other declarations without it. (at least, the Win7 version of IE10 does)

Comment: @Knetic - Thanks for this, glad I didn't follow the so-called best practice. For the sake of 100 bytes, it's worth adding prefixes.

Comment: @Jamie There is such thing has 'best-practice' with css level 3. The world wants Photoshop for a browser.

Comment: adding to the confusion, this blogpost suggests ie10 does support the unprefixed syntax: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/06/25/unprefixed-css3-gradients-in-ie10.aspx

Comment: MSDN blog entry is gone somehow and here is the cached page: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Dfg2-89INWwJ:blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/06/25/unprefixed-css3-gradients-in-ie10.aspx

Comment: According to [Can I Use...](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients), IE10 supports gradients without prefix.

Comment: My guess is that the `-ms` syntax was introduced in a preview release of IE10, then they replaced it with the standard syntax before the IE10 gold release.

Answer (score 1):

I tested in Windows 7, IE10.0.9200.17148 from the [modern.ie](https://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools)

And `background-image: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.03) 31%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 32%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);` works.

[image: ie10-gradient]

If you have an IE10, test it here:
https://fiddle.jshell.net/txLtok1w/1/

...and report whether gradient is shown or not, together with your OS and IE version/minor version.